# Removing dateline in polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, polygon

I am using the marine boundaries data from [MarineRegions.org](http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php) and I'm trying to use cylindrical equal area with a -160 central meridian.  I successfully removed the dateline from polygons basically using [the method outlined in this GISSE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123038/mapping-russia-intl-dateline-splitting-polygon).  However, the marine boundaries dataset the polygons are singlepart, even with the split and ArcGIS is not allowing me to explode to multi-part (to then dissolve)... the option is grey-ed out.  Can anyone provide a solution to the polygon-crossing-international-dateline problem when the original polygon is singlepart?

Basically, is there a way [to accomplish this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242068/dissolving-reprojected-features-split-into-two-parts-by-international-dateline) in ArcGIS?

Comment: I downloaded the eez_v10 (polys). They look okay to me (multipart). Is it occurring with all polygons that touch the dateline? If not, which ones?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my terminology is wrong but there are multiple polygons yet only a single line in the attribute table... thus unable to use the merge or dissolve tool.