# QGIS 3.x: How to recenter the NASA Blue Marble on the Pacific

Tags: qgis, tiles

I am working on a personal project that shows sailing routes of the pacific on the NASA Blue Marble imagery. But I am stuck...

How do I go about splitting and rearranging the [NASA Blue Marble](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/collection/1484/blue-marble) raster so that it is centered on the Pacific?

Comment: Similar questions have been answered regarding vector layers, like this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242068/dissolving-reprojected-features-split-into-two-parts-by-international-dateline. Not sure if the same methods will apply.

Comment: How about using `EPSG:3832` as the project CRS?

Answer (score 2):

gprojector Software, its great for Raster https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/