# QGIS world map projection with solid Russia (10 degrees over)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm fairly new to QGIS. I have a world map, standard WGS84 with 10 degree graticules (see map).

How do I "shift" the whole map over just 10 degrees to give me a complete world map with a solid (unbroken area) Russia?

See red line on map.

[image]

I don't need the size or anything else to change, I just want it to be centered 10 degrees over.

[World][1\

[image: Info]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I absolutely do not understand the instructions given by the "duplicate" question's answer. The writer mentions "delete the first layer", and to which I say "which layer is that?". Where should the text file be placed? I know how to find the Text delimited layer, but not sure how to add the file? I don't know if my version of Qgis (QGIS 2.18.14) is giving me different options, but I'm not seeing any of the prompts.

Comment: I think you should add your problems as a comment to the linked answer. Anyway, I suggest to look into https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123038/mapping-russia-intl-dateline-splitting-polygon for your russia cut issue.