# Far East Russia Detachment

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using Leaflet JS with a modified GeoJSON file of world contries to display a choropleth, like this:

[image: World map]

Is there any way to display the far-eastern part of Russia as a contiguous entity? Rather than it being split to due to its coordinates.

Comment: I guess it's not about Leaflet but GeoJSON. In your GeoJSON file, far-eastern part of Russia may/must be seperate polygon.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123038/mapping-russia-intl-dateline-splitting-polygon and the questions the `Linked` section there.

Comment: Another answer more suited specifically for Leaflet is https://stackoverflow.com/a/40544502/4768502

Comment: Ivan's answer above did the trick. I just added 360 to the x axis of the relevant geoJSON and used turf.js's union function, which can very quickly be used to merge polygons.